# AWS S3 presigned url issue with asterisk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading files threw presigned s3 urls but I do not know why I have a 403 when I try to upload a file with an `*`

This is my server command to generate signed url

```
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const client = new S3Client({ region: "eu-central-1" });

const bucket = 'test';

module.exports.getUploadUrl = (fileName, fileType) => {
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
        ACL: "public-read",
        Bucket: bucket,
        ContentType: fileType,
        Key: fileName
    });

    return getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 60 })
        .then(result => ({ signedRequest: result, url: `https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}` }))
}
```

In this step everything works fine but then on front when I want to upload

```
fetch(json.signedRequest, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: file
})
.then(response)
```

I have a `403` status code and an empty body

I tried with `with*.pdf` and it fails but for example `with.pdf`, `with+.pdf`, `with .pdf` works

Comment: Are you sure wildecards are supported in pre-signed url? This [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=809891&tstart=0) indicates that they are not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Amazon S3 documentation, the * special character is valid.

[Creating object key names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html)

I wanted to test this use case, so I created a file named

> foo*.txt

and uploaded this via a **S3Presigner** client. This worked perfectly:

[image]

The difference is I implemented this using S3 Java V2 API. My example is here:

```
public class GeneratePresignedUrlAndUploadObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GeneratePresignedUrlAndUploadObject <bucketName> <keyName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the name of the Amazon S3 bucket. \n\n" +
                "    keyName - a key name that represents a text file. \n" ;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = "<MyBucket>";  //args[0];
        String keyName = "foo*.txt"; //args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        signBucket(presigner, bucketName, keyName);
        presigner.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[presigned.java2.generatepresignedurl.main]
    public static void signBucket(S3Presigner presigner, String bucketName, String keyName) {

        try {
            PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(keyName)
                    .contentType("text/plain")
                    .build();

            PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                    .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                    .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
                    .build();

            PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);


            String myURL = presignedRequest.url().toString();
            System.out.println("Presigned URL to upload a file to: " +myURL);
            System.out.println("Which HTTP method needs to be used when uploading a file: " +
                    presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());

            // Upload content to the Amazon S3 bucket by using this URL
            URL url = presignedRequest.url();

            // Create the connection and use it to upload the new object by using the presigned URL
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain");
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write("This text was uploaded as an object by using a presigned URL.");
            out.close();

            connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP response code is " + connection.getResponseCode());

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

So this shows the using a * character in the key name when using a pre-signed URL is supported. It looks like your JavaScript code may not be valid. Please refer to the S3 JavaScript example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src/s3_put_presignedURL.ts